# How do I verify a tape backup with tar?

Tags: backup, tar, freebsd

I am doing some tape backups with:

```
mt eom
tar cv Projects*
```

Note: $TAPE variable is set to `/dev/nsa0`

I would like to verify that backup has been properly done, via `md5sum`. Therefore I could do:

```
tar cvf test.tar Projects*
```

And I would like to compare with the tar stored in the tape.

However, I do not know how could I extract the whole tar file in the tape into a backupInTape.tar file so I can do:

```
md5sum test.tar
md5sum backupInTape.tar
```

This is what I have tried to do something like that (at the right location in the tape, verified with `tar tv`):

```
tar xv > backupInTape.tar
```

But it still extracts everything.

I am using FreeBSD 12.1

Comment: As you say, `tar xv` will read the tape and extract the archive. Perhaps you just need `dd` to read the tape and save the archive as a file.

Comment: It might be a basic question, but could you please elaborate on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the data from tape with the dd command, EG:

```
dd if="$TAPE" of=data-from-tape.tar bs=126
```

Check your 'tar' command's default blocksize, and replace the 126 with it.  I believe Gnu tar uses 126, but other tar's may still default to 20 or something.  With some tape drives, the blocksize matters a lot.

Also, see https://serverfault.com/questions/293605/check-integrity-of-tar-gz-backup

Also, Gnu tar can --diff to confirm that a tar archive is correct, byte for byte.